# passport JWT 'Unauthorized' Node

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm making authorizing with token and when I test with postman, I keep getting 'Unauthorized' after logged in and go to profile

Login code:

```
router.post('/authentication', (request, response, next) => {
    const email = request.body.email;
    const password = request.body.password;

    userModel.getUserByEmail(email, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            if (!user) {
                console.log('User does not exists!');
                response.json({ success: false, msg: 'User does not exists!' });
            } else {
                userModel.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    else {
                        if (!isMatch) {
                            response.json({ success: false, msg: 'Password do not match!' });
                        } else {
                            const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
                                expiresIn: 86400 // 1 day
                            });

                            response.json({
                                success: true,
                                token: "JWT " + token,
                                user: {
                                    id: user._id,
                                    name: user.name,
                                    email: user.email,
                                    role: user.role
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

passport.js

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

const userModel = require('../models/usersModel');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function (passport) {
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;

    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {

        userModel.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id, (err, user) => {
            console.log(jwt_payload);
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
}
```

tested route :

```
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (request, response, next) => {
    response.json({ user: request.user });
});
```

(PS: I tried console.log(jwt_payload); and shows nothing in console. Still stucking in this please help. I'm a starter. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get your jwt token, you should send it in every request.

header: authorization: JWT "token"

Are you doing it?

[image]

Comment: Yes. I'm doing it

Comment: Did you try to remove the expiration to see what happens?

Comment: Thanks, you remained me it. It works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I really forgot to add authorization.

Comment: Glad to help! :-)